# How to set android TextView to implement inversion of letters?

Tags: android

For example,A converted to ∀!thanks.

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:rotation = "180"
```

for example:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="A"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:rotation="180"/>
```

Only available in API 11+

Comment: OH,Thanks,it's helpfull!But the error in API 9 is 07-01 10:13:59.539: E/AndroidRuntime(21762): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setRotation

Comment: how can I do for API 11-?

Comment: It is Only available in API 11+